# VSFTPD silently drops connection

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

`vsftpd` disconnects client after login without any warnings in logs,

`/etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_root=/home/[username]/Public
anon_upload_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
isolate_network=NO
listen=YES
listen_port=666
local_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
seccomp_sandbox=NO
write_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

Connection attempt

```
lftp localhost:666
ls
'ls' at 0 [Delaying before reconnect: 12]
```

`/var/log/vsftpd.log`

```
Sat Dec 2 19:30:29 2023 [pid 1] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "127.0.0.1", anon password <no password>"
```

There's nothing after OK LOGIN, connection just drops.

What I've tried:

- local user anonymous
- local user non-anonymous
- user on local network on different machine anonymous
- user on local network on different machine not anonymous
- using lftp
- using FTP support on Dolphin from Plasma

Every time login succeeds and connection drops.
How can I troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 0):

According to [4.7 VSFTPD reset connect via LIST command](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon)

> ```
> seccomp_sandbox=NO
> ```
>
> into the vsftpd.conf file fixes this issue